# Transferring tables between 2 connections using a MySQL query

Tags: mysql, database, navicat

I manage multiple databases using Navicat for MySQL. This allows me to transfer tables from one connection to another. However, I would like to replicate this process from within a MySQL query (eg. when a certain condition is met.) Unfortunately it only works when creating a new table within the same connection.

```
SET @create_table := IF(@tmp >= 0, 'CREATE TABLE database2.table1 SELECT * FROM database1.table1', 'no');
SELECT @create_table;
PREPARE stmt_create FROM @create_table;
EXECUTE stmt_create;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt_create;
```

Does anyone know of a good way to do this?

Comment: I don't think it's possible through a tool. It maybe possible using command line, probably like a batch file command-prompt or powershell (in Windows OS).

Comment: If you are running your queries from a script file, then the `COPY` metacommand of `execsql.py` (https://pypi.org/project/execsql/) will copy a table between two databases within your script.  Disclaimer: I wrote execsql.